# How do I get the objective-c function call graph in a Xcode-prj

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, doxygen, static-analysis

I am a rookie to develop a tool to static analysis objective-c file with clang now.
And I want to find a way to get the funtion call graph with text (that I can analyze in the program) in the xcode-project but I can't find a good way to do it.
How do I get the graph with some tools?Or is it having a way that I can analyze the code with clang that provide for me.

Comment: This is what you need https://github.com/vampirewalk/ObjectGraph-Xcode ?

Comment: @Proton Hi,Proton.The tool just a ObjectGraph not a function call graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt static analyzer-checker for CLANG which dumps in the output in two formats. 1) Purely screen based 2) in DOT format for image generation.

For example, call graph of a single file in text format

```
clang -Xclang -analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=debug.DumpCallGraph <filename.cpp>
```

And call graph of a single file in DOT format

```
clang -Xclang -analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=debug.ViewCallGraph <filename.cpp>
```

For your XCode Project it will be something like this: (more about scan-build [here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html))

```
scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker debug.DumpCallGraph xcodebuild
```

Comment: thanks，I hava run the command 'scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker debug.ViewCallGraph xcodebuild'..and where I can find  the dot file?

Comment: If the above command successully ran. You will have one or multiple files in the /tmp directory. Usually it should be something like `/tmp/CallGraph-<some text>.dot`